# I have a page with some information I want to call some of it on another page using php

Tags: php

I have a login page and I want if the user wrote the correct password, but for each user with a password when he is transferred to another page, he appears to him, Welcome Bishoy or Hani according to the written password

HTML

```
<form action="INDEX.PHP" method="POST" class="two">
    <div>
        <button class="yeu"  id="submit" type="submit" name="submit">LOGIN</button>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" minlength="14" maxlength="14" required>
    </div>
    <div id="user" style="color: black; font-size: 20px; text-align: left;">
        <pre style="color: black; font-size: 20px; text-align: left; display: none;"></pre>
</form>
```

LOGIN.PHP

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    if ($username === "01234567891012"){
        $username = "PISHOY";
        header('Location: no_error.php');
        exit;
    }
    elseif ($username === "01234567891013"){
        $username = "HANY";
        header('Location: no_error.php');
        exit;
    }
    elseif ($username === "01234567891014"){
        $username = "ALI";
        header('Location: no_error.php');
        exit;
    }
    elseif ($username === "01234567891015"){
        $username = "PISH";
        header('Location: no_error.php');
        exit;

    }
else{
header("location: error.php");
}
}
?>
```

PAGE2

```
<div id="true"><?php
         include 'index_p.php';
    echo "HELLO $username";?>
```

What is the problem

Comment: The problem is that ordinary variables don't persist across different requests. Learn about Sessions, please.

Comment: please write code and thank you

Comment: Er, no that's not how this site works. We don't work for yoy. You go and learn about sessions (it's not difficult and there are many tutorials already available online) and then try to use it in your code to achieve what you need. If you still have a problem with it after that, you can update your question to show what you tried and what your new problem is. we don't just provide a free write-my-code service without any effort from you first.

Comment: But you told me

The problem is that normal variables do not persist across different requests. Know the sessions, please.
And I am a beginner in the PHP language, how do I understand what the problem is

Comment: By learning how to use sessions. Session is the place you can store temporary variables so they will be available across multiple requests by the same user. https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-sessions.php is just one of many places you can start to learn. Being a beginner does not excuse you from basic research. If I say "learn about sessions" it implies you can use it to solve your problem...so the first thing you so is go and learn what a session is and how to use it. And I think, even as a beginner, you would then be able to see from those basics how it can help you